# How do you install Tomcat 6 as a service using the Wix ServiceInstall Tag?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, tomcat6

How do you install Tomcat 6 as a service using the Wix ServiceInstall Tag?  Is there a way to do it, or do I need to use a custom action to call the executable or batch file that comes with it to install the service?

Comment: Reopen please. I feel this question has a valid topic. I wish the people closing it had said why they consider it off topic in comments (why is this not enforced by the site?) - I had a very similar question myself and would like to be able to ask it without getting my question closed. This question raises a specific programming problem that took me hours to develop a solution for and I would now like to answer this question with a pile of code so other developers don't have to go through the same work I did.

Comment: I do not see why this is off topic... seems perfectly relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The Windows Installer requires the KeyPath of the Component with a ServiceInstall element ot be the file that is the service. Said a different way, you must mark the Tomcat 6 service executable (tomcat.exe?) File element with KeyPath="yes". Then put the ServiceInstall element in the same Component.

If you are not installing the Tomcat 6 service executable yourself then you do have to turn to a custom action. Remember with a custom action to think about repair/upgrade/uninstall/patching and rollback for all that. Custom actions are a lot of work.

Comment: Have you tried this personally?  I haven't managed to make it work this way.

Comment: You have no idea who Rob is, do you? :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the ServiceInstall tag, you will need to manually add a few Registry keys. This is because Tomcat uses Procrun to run as service.

You can try installing the service using service.bat and inspect the registry keys in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\ProcRun 2.0\

For reference:
commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html